# Azure deploy agent (azagent) demon doesn't start after reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure-devops, azure-releases

I installed a azure deploy agent on a Ubuntu server.
The agent works fine but won't come up after reboot the machine.
How to run it as a demon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The agent works fine but won't come up after reboot the machine. How to run it as a demon?

You could try to install the agent as a systemd service instead of interactively.

Please check the document [Run as a systemd service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#run-as-a-systemd-service) for some more details.

Alternatively, you could use `crontab -e` to create your [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) jobs.

Comment: svc,sh script need some tweaking for my ubuntu version but crontab is good enough